# Extract lines from a text file based on a parameter to a single line

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I'm quite new to scripting so I appreciate any help. I have a text file that in some cases can be quite long, each section of text lines can be around 6/7 lines long. It is a logfile and each section starts with the word timestamp. There is a blank line between each section of lines. Each section line ends with a semi-colon.

```
timestamp=201706291035.....;
  line 2;
  line 3;
  line 4;
  line 5;
  line 6;
  line 7;

timestamp=201706291038.....;
  line 2;
  line 3;
  line 4;
  line 5;
  line 6;
```

I need to be able to extract each section out to another text file in a single line. Preferably without the last semi-colon.

```
timestamp=201706291035.....;line 2;line 3;line 4;line 5;line 6;line 7
timestamp=201706291038.....;line 2;line 3;line 4;line 5;line 6
```

Is that enough information for a solution?

Here's a direct example:

timestamp=2017-06-28-01.01.35.080576;
  event status=0;
  userid=user1;
  authid=user1;
  application id=10.10.10.10.11111.12345678901;
  application name=GUI;

timestamp=2017-06-28-01.01.36.096486;
  event status=0;
  userid=user1;
  authid=user1;
  application id=10.10.10.10.11111.12345678901;
  application name=GUI;
  statement text=SELECT table.field, table.field, table.field from database where table.field = value

After I run the scripts @steeldriver, the source and destination file looks the same.

Comment: I boldly edited based on what I _think_ was meant, do check if I got it right.

Comment: Yes, the example is correct now. When I entered the example, it ended up all on the same line. Sorry.

Comment: Is there an empty line before the timestamp?

Comment: Typically the logfile doesn't have an empty line at the beginning prior to the timestamp. If it does, I can remove it.

Comment: I screwed up with the example, each line after the timestamp is indented 2 spaces. I'm not sure if that would make a difference though.

Answer (score 4):

This could be done with idiomatic awk like so:

```
awk '$1=$1' RS= OFS= infile
```

Output:

```
timestamp=201706291035.....;line 2;line 3;line 4;line 5;line 6;line 7;
timestamp=201706291038.....;line 2;line 3;line 4;line 5;line 6;
```

#### Explanation

There is a lot packed in here. Basically there are three steps:

1. First the input is split into records based on the record separator (`RS`).
2. Each record is split into fields based on the field separator (`FS`).
3. When printing, the output field separator (`OFS`) is used as the field delimiter.

When awk parses its input, there are several implicit rules at work. The data is read, one record at a time, records being separated by `RS` (default is `\n`). When `RS` is empty, as in the above example, an empty line delimits records. Thus each section is read in as a record.

In order to force `awk` to replace `FS` with `OFS` we set the first field `$1` to itself.

#### Edit

As noted by *steeldriver*, the OP wants to remove trailing semi-colons. Shamelessly copied:

```
awk '{ sub(/;$/,"",$NF); $1=$1 } 1' RS= OFS= infile
```

Comment: Why not just `awk '$1=$1' RS= filename`  We'd only need the `RS` here.

Comment: Again, brand new here, so would the command be like this? awk '$1=$1' RS= FS='\n' OFS= test.txt > single.txt where test.txt is the original file.

Comment: @david you only need `awk '$1=$1' > "single.txt" RS= test.txt`

Comment: `awk 'sub(/;$/,"",$NF)' RS= OFS= file` would strip the trailing semicolon from the last field, as the OP also requested. (Note that in this form, it only prints lines for which the replacement is successful; if that's not the desired result then `awk '{sub(/;$/,"",$NF)} 1' RS= OFS= file`).

Comment: @val0x00ff: Right, but according to the OP we also need `OFS=`

Comment: This is great, thanks guys. I think I'm still doing something wrong as the results file looks like the source file. Could you give me examples using text.txt as source and single.txt as destination excluding the semi-colon at the end? I tried awk '{ sub(/;$/,"",$NF); $1=$1 } 1' RS= OFS= test.txt > single.txt.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the following way:

```
perl -lF';\n?' -00ne '$,=";"; print @F' yourfile
```

---

### Output

```
timestamp=201706291035.....;line 2;line 3;line 4;line 5;line 6;line 7
timestamp=201706291038.....;line 2;line 3;line 4;line 5;line 6
```

---

### Working

1. *Perl options*

   a) `-l` => ORS="\n" + RS = "\n"

   b) `-F';\n?'` => will make the FS to be a semicolon followed by an optional newline.

   c) `-00` => will make RS= thereby enabling paragraph mode.

   d) `-n` => will enable the implicit file read-in + explicit printing.
2. Main: `$,=;` will make OFS a semicolon, `@F` is the fields which have been carved out of the current record `$_` based on the `FS`.

Answer (score 0):

If there's an empty line before the timestamp, you can use a simple

```
perl -pe 'chomp unless /^$/'
```

If the newlines are not there, you need to remember the previous line.

```
perl -pe 'chomp; print "\n" if $. > 1 && /^timestamp=/; print }{ print "\n"'
```

Comment: Don't know anything about perl. If the source file is test.txt and the destination file is single.txt, what would the command line look like? Thanks for your help.

Comment: As with anything else, `perl -pe '...' < test.txt > single.txt`

Comment: Thanks. Does it make a difference if the lines following the timestamp line, are indented by 2 spaces? The output file looks the same as the input file.

Comment: @david: The code only checks the empty lines by `^$` or the substring `timestamp=` at the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest answer for the use case would be:

```
awk '$1=$1' > "single.txt" RS= test.txt
```

As `RS` was explained by Thor, we only need `RS` here to get our result.

Comment: When I run the above command the output I get is - statement text=SELECT table.field, table.field, table.field from database where table.field = value. This is the last line in the original file.

Answer (score 0):

Just because, here's a way to do it in `sed`

Take as our starting point this one-liner from [Peter Krumins' Sed One-Liners Explained, Part I: File Spacing, Numbering and Text Conversion and Substitution](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/)

> 39. Append a line to the next if it ends with a backslash "\".
>
>     ```
>     sed -e :a -e '/\\$/N; s/\\\n//; ta'
>     ```
>
> The first expression ':a' creates a named label "a". The second
>   expression looks to see if the current line ends with a backslash "\".
>   If it does, it joins it with the line following it using the "N"
>   command. Then the slash and the newline between joined lines get
>   erased with "s/\\n//" command. If the substitution was successful we
>   branch to the beginning of expression and do the same again, in hope
>   that we might have another backslash. If the substitution was not
>   successful, the line did not end with a backslash and we print it out.

replacing `\\` by `;` and adjusting the replacement to leave the `;` but remove the leading spaces, we get

```
$ sed -e :a -e '/;$/N; s/\n *//; ta' infile
timestamp=201706291035.....;line 2;line 3;line 4;line 5;line 6;line 7;

timestamp=201706291038.....;line 2;line 3;line 4;line 5;line 6;
```

Close! now we want to squeeze out the blank line - we can do that by testing if the pattern *ends* in a newline (i.e. the appended line is empty) and if so printing *up to* the newline and then discarding the pattern:

```
$ sed -e :a -e '/;$/N; /\n$/{P;d;}; s/\n *//; ta' infile
timestamp=201706291035.....;line 2;line 3;line 4;line 5;line 6;line 7;
timestamp=201706291038.....;line 2;line 3;line 4;line 5;line 6;
```

Now we just need to trim the trailing `;`. One way to do that is to remove each `;` as we append the line to the pattern space, and then re-insert it when we discard the newline:

```
$ sed -e :a -e '/;$/{s///;N;}; /\n$/{P;d;}; s/\n */;/; ta' infile
timestamp=201706291035.....;line 2;line 3;line 4;line 5;line 6;line 7
timestamp=201706291038.....;line 2;line 3;line 4;line 5;line 6
```

The final `;` doesn't get re-inserted because we've already eaten the newline with the `{P;d;}` so the `s//\n  /;/` substitution doesn't get applied.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work for me. The script runs without error but the source and destination file look the same.

Comment: timestamp=2017-06-28-01.01.35.080576;<br/>
  event status=0;<br/>
  userid=user1;<br/>
  authid=user1;<br/>
  application id=10.10.10.10.11111.12345678901;<br/>
  application name=GUI;<br/>
<br/>
timestamp=2017-06-28-01.01.36.096486;<br/>
  event status=0;<br/>
  userid=user1;<br/>
  authid=user1;<br/>
  application id=10.10.10.10.11111.12345678901;<br/>
  application name=GUI;<br/>
  statement text=SELECT table.field, table.field, table.field from database where table.field = value<br/>

Comment: @david it's hopeless posting as a comment - please edit your original question